# glGenBuffers does not set buffer

Tags: c++, c, opengl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any reason why `glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID)` unsuccessfully allocates an ID into `bufferID`?

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    GLuint bufferID = 0;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &bufferID );
    printf("bufferID: %d\n", bufferID);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled as

```
g++ -o glTest glTest.c -lGL -lGLU
```

Outputs:

```
arrID: 0
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS EC2 g2.2xlarge instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a current opengl context to call any gl functions. You can use either glx or egl to create a context and make it current.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a GL context, so all bets are off. Calling any GL function without having a context current to the calling thread is completely undefined behavior.